# Submit to Mac App Store with Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store

I'm submitting from the Organizer and I get as far as "Choose an application and code signing identity".  After that I just get the spinning circle which lasts for hours until I cancel and start over.  I've already submitted this same app once, but the first time it was rejected by the reviewer because of a new requirement in itunesconnect that was added after the first submission.  So I made the change in itunesconnect, changed the version, and rebuilt the app.  No other changes.

I've run into this before, but I just kept trying and eventually I would get to the loading screen.  The app id and the code signing identity are valid, and I didn't receive any errors during validation, so I'm not sure where to look for the problem.

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1.